# Firebase: Paging use endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Mydata:

info
_1
___id: 1
___year: 2020
_2
___id: 2
___year: 2019
_3
___id: 3
___year: 2020
_4
___id: 4
___year: 2020
_5
___id: 5
___year: 2017
[...]

In first page, I use
`ref().child("info").orderByChild("year").equalTo(2020).limitToLast(5).get()`
It return last 5 info with year=2020 (ex: id=23, 22, 21, 20 and 17). Now, in page 2, I use id=17 to continue get last 5 last info. I need something like:
 `ref().child("info").orderByChild("year").equalTo(2020).endAt(id=17).limitToLast(5).get()`
How to do oderByChild Year and Id together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `endAt` method (as well as `startAt`, `endAfter`, and `startAfter`) take two arguments. The first is the value of the property you order/filter on, and the second argument is the key of the node to use in case there are multiple matches for the property.

So to end at the node where `year` is `2020` and the node with key equal to `17`, your combined query can look like this:

```
ref().child("info").orderByChild("year").endAt(2020, 17).limitToLast(5)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!